# what does git rm do as opposed to deleting by OS and git add

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm

If we want to delete a file (say file1.txt) and stop the git repo to track it, it is said that we should use `git rm file1.txt` and then `git commit -m "..."`  it. But deleting from the working directory by OS, `rm file1.txt`, `add .` and then `git commit -m "..."` do the same. what are their difference?

Comment: please provide the specific commands for `git add`

Answer (score 5):

There's no difference. `git add` of  a tracked file you've removed from the work tree removes the index entry. A tracked file is what's in the work tree and the index record for it, there's nothing else, your sequence is exactly `git rm`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `git rm` command deletes files both from the Git repository as well as the filesystem.

Deleting it manually using `rm (file)`, won't remove it from the Git repo unless you do the following (after deleting that file):

```
git add *

git commit -m
```

Comment: Note that `git add *` *might not work*. It *might* work, but it might not. However, `git add .` generally *will* work, even though `git add *` does or does not work. Exercise for you: Why? What conditions make `git add *` work, and what conditions make it fail? (This is not a simple exercise, especially if you only work with Windows.)